# What should be the REST API (URL) for a user to be assigned to multiple territories

Tags: rest, web-api, asp.net-mvc-web-api

In our application we have a user who can be assigned multiple territories.
What is the best way to expose the REST API?

Should it be as :

[POST] www.xyz.com/Territory/User

OR

[POST] www.xyz.com/User/Territory

BODY :

{
   "UserId" : 6,
  "TerritoryId" : [1,2,5]
}

I am designing this application using .net WEB API 2, so should the above action be placed in User controller or Territory controller or shall I create UserTerritory as a new controller? 
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your identifiers.

```
 GET /715f9784-4b51-461a-b3ee-fdf2823c25cb
```

is perfectly fine, as far as REST is concerned.

```
 www.xyz.com/Territory/User
 www.xyz.com/User/Territory
```

The only real difference between these two, seen from the client, is the way that [relative references](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2) work.  Where are dot-segments going to be useful?

```
www.xyz.com/Territory/User + ../Foo = www.xyz.com/Territory/Foo
www.xyz.com/User/Territory + ../Foo = www.xyz.com/User/Foo
```

If you are more interested in other things about `Territory`, then putting it at the root makes it easier to reach other resources starting with that stem; if you are more interested in other resources about `User`, then that belongs up top.

The good news: HTTP has [standard semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.7) in place if you get it "wrong"

```
GET /Territory/User/...

307 Temporary Redirect
Location: /User/Territory/...
```

Answer (score -2):

Because you are wisely using POST you don't have any parameters in the URL

Thus, you can use either or both or simply

```
www.xyz.com/User/AddUser
{ "UserId" : 6, "TerritoryId" : [1,2,5] }
```

If you are GETing users you would expect

```
/Territory/{territoryId}/Users
```

To return only the users in the selected territory

Whereas the Users controller would be used for more generic queries, possibly requiring a POST

```
POST /User/GetUserByTerritoryIds  
{[1,2,3,4....]}
```

Comment: I like to avoid verbs when a resource name can be used in this case "Add" on AddUser could be replaced with /Territory/{terriority}/Users and a POST that adds a user to a given territory.

Comment: It sure makes the examples clearer though doesnt it